# Resque Pool launch failure on macOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, macos-high-sierra

`resque-pool` fails to launch resque workers on macOS High Sierra

**Error message**

bjc[5921]: +[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead. Set a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Researched and found an answer through [the accepted answer for this Stackexchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46591470/unicorn-with-ruby-2-4-1-causing-weird-crash) - it relates to Unicorn but very much applies to my issue.

Apple made safty related changes on High Sierra when it comes to forking processes.

Holger's answer provides a workaround to disable the new safety feature in High Sierra through an environment variable.

```
OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES
```

This solved my issue. I am now able to launch the resque workers through `resque-pool`.

#### Ruby

More details on the issue for [Ruby context is discussed here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14009)

I [raised an issue on the resque-pool gem](https://github.com/nevans/resque-pool/issues/168). But possibly it is more something to be addressed in Ruby. I am not expert enough ...